# How to access WPF MainWindows Controls from another class in the same namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have MainWindows.cs like that:

```
namespace LiniaProdukcyjna
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
}
```

And I have CSilnik class:

```
namespace LiniaProdukcyjna
{
    class CSilnik
    {
        ICollection<CLinia> linie;

        public void permut(int k, int n, int[] nums)
        {
            int i, j, tmp;

            /* when k > n we are done and should print */
            if (k <= n)
            {

                for (i = k; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    tmp = nums[i];
                    for (j = i; j > k; j--)
                    {
                        nums[j] = nums[j - 1];
                    }
                    nums[k] = tmp;

                    /* recurse on k+1 to n */
                    permut(k + 1, n, nums);

                    for (j = k; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        nums[j] = nums[j + 1];
                    }
                    nums[i] = tmp;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                linie.Add(new CLinia(nums));
                // here i want to do something with ListView in MainWindow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and CLinia class:

```
namespace LiniaProdukcyjna
{
    class CLinia
    {
        int koszt;
        int[] kolejnosc;

        public CLinia(int[] inKolejnosc)
        {
            kolejnosc = inKolejnosc;
        }

    }
}
```

And I have ListView control in MainWindow.
I want to modify ListView "lista" in MainWindow, but I cannot access to them.
What I have to do to accessing to controls like: lista.Items.Add ?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of ListView? if it is a control defined in the MainWindow.xaml all you need to do is add a Name <ListeView Name="MyListView"> then you can access it in the MainWindow.xaml.cs via MyListView.Items.Add()

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is Create a constructor of `SomeClass` in which you want to access the `listview` and pass the reference of `listview` in `constructor` whenever you are creating the instance of `SomeClass`. In this way you will be able to access `listview` in any `class`

for example

in MainWindow.xaml.cs file

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(listView);
}
```

in some other class where you want to access listview

```
public SomeClass
{
    ListView _ListViewRef;

    public SomeClass(ListView listView)
    {
    _LisViewRef = listView;
    }

   SomeMethod()
   {
   //here you can play with listview
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is actually not a great idea to pass UI controls between classes.

You can only edit controls (such as listviews, textboxes etc..) in the class that controls the window.

You can, however, make another partial class that just splits your Main Window class.

If you ever pass something to another class, you can pass it this way:

```
Public SomeClass(string text)
{
}

//Create an object of 'SomeClass'
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(textBox.text);
```

Or you can pass the user control properties through methods.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

In MainWindow.xaml you can create static instance of control you want to access;

```
 public static StackPanel stackPanel;
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // set stackpanel for logging
        stackPanel = stackPanel1;
    }
```

Then you can access it from outside class like;

```
MainWindow.stackPanel
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Event Handler in Form2 and subscribe in Form1

```
public event EventHandler<UpdateListBoxEventArgs> UpdateListBox;     
      converter.UpdateListBox += 
 new EventHandler<CVEConverter.UpdateListBoxEventArgs>(AddToListBox);       
 public class UpdateListBoxEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly string lbTerminalText;

        public UpdateListBoxEventArgs(string lbText)
        {
            this.lbTerminalText = lbText;
        }

        public string lbTerminalWindowText
        {
            get { return lbTerminalText; }
        }
    }
```